# Changing object dimensions along Y axis - scales Z axis

Tags: transforms, coordinates, dimensions

I am a bit confused about axis systems in Blender. In the first figure - the green and blue represent the Y and Z axis. When I translate the object in Y,Z directions it moves perfectly. However, when I change the object dimensions in Z direction it causes the object to change in the Y direction. [image: Original Object]  [image: Object after change in dimensions along Z axis]

Also, in the first figure the dimensions in (Y,Z) are (725,2809) respectively - but obviously the extent of object in Y is much greater than in the Z direction. This makes me suspect that the dimensions are being shown in a coordinate system different from the one displayed on the screen. Any hints on how do I find it?

For sake of completeness - the airplane shown in the figure was imported as a .obj file. Since, it was composed a number of smaller meshes - I joined all these meshes into a single object and moved the geometry to origin. This is what is shown in figure 1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because the object is rotated 90° around the X axis.

So blender is scaling the object around the *local* Z, then rotating the object so that the local Z is aligned with the global Y.

To fix this, apply the rotation with <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>*> Rotation*.

Comment: So this means that rotation and location are modified in the global coordinate system - it does not really makes sense otherwise.  Whereas, scale and dimensions are modified in the local coordinate system.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds to me like you scaling the object in object mode when it has a rotation applied to it. If you want that then gandalf's answer is all you need.

In the future you may wish to do all of your rotating and scaling in *Edit Mode* rather than *Object Mode*. This will prevent you from having to apply the transformations.

A simple way to see if transformations need to be applied.

[image]

A usefull post to look at:
[Why is it important to apply transformation to an objects data?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation)